# Create 1D Arrary with n text boxes in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I wanna create an 1D array with n text boxes in Windows Phone 8 ( I had succeeded in Windows Form )
1) In `MainPage.xaml` :

```
 <TextBox x:Name="tbx_a" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="29,265,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="a:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Random" Content="Random" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,385,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei" FontSize="20" Click="btn_Random_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Array" Content="Create" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284,385,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="130" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei" FontSize="20" Click="btn_Array_Click"/>
```

2) In `MainPage.xaml.cs` :

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage 
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
    }
    TextBox[] Node;

    int[] a;

    int n ; // Number of boxes User wanna see in screen

    **Label[] label_box; //Label of box: 15,23, 82, etc...:First problem here : DON'T HAVE LABEL NAMESPACE**

    public void create_array ()
    {

    label_box = new Label[n];  // From problem above
    a = new int[n];
    Node = new TextBox[n];

    tbx_a.Width = 20;
    tbx_a.Height = 20;
    tbx_a.FontSize = 18  ;

        for (int i=0; i< n ; i++)
        {
            //NODE
            a[i] = i;
            Node[i] = new TextBox();

            Node[i].Text = a[i].ToString();

            Node[i].Width = 20;
            Node[i].Height = 20;
            Node[i].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            Node[i].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            ***this.Controls.Add (Node[i]);  // Second problem : DON'T HAVE CONTROLS NAMESPACE***

            label_box[i] = new Label();
            label_box[i].Text = a[i].ToString();

            label_box[i].Width = 20;
            label_box[i].Height = 20;

            ***this.Controls.Add(label_box[i]);  // Second problem above***
        }
    }

    private void btn_Random_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = r.Next(100);
            Node[i].Text = a[i].ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btn_Array_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        create_array();
    }       
}
```

3) I wanna see result in my phone screen after I input n = 8 and choose random button :

```
[23][01][57][92][71][08][38][49]
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is your issue? Do you get any errors?

Comment: There had 2 problems when I created BOXES and LABEL ( number ) for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a number of TextBoxes you've nearly completed your task, there are couple of little mistakes you've made:

- First of all you should provide a method that would convert your `TextBox a:` to a numer `n` - otherwise you always create 0 TextBoxes. In this case you should also remove `a:` from `Text` of the `TextBox` as it will be easier to convert.
- in your creating method you need a Control in your Page to which you will add your TextBoxes - I'll use for example `StackPanel`
- as for your Label - you can make it for example with `TextBlock`

In XAML file it can look like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
        <TextBlock Text="a:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbx_a" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="80" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="8" TextAlignment="Center" Width="100" FontFamily="Arial" />
        <Button x:Name="btn_Random" Content="Random" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="65" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei" FontSize="20" Click="btn_Random_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Array" Content="Create" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="65" Width="130" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei" FontSize="20" Click="btn_Array_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Name="BoxStack" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

As you can see I've used here `StackPanel` with a name `BoxStack` - to which I'll add my TextBoxes. I've also put it inside `ScrollViewer` so that when there are many TextBoxes I will be able to scroll.

Then the code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbx_a.TextChanged += (s, e) => { n = Convert.ToInt32(tbx_a.Text); };
    }
    TextBox[] Node;
    int[] a;

    int n = 8; // Number of boxes User wanna see in screen

    public void create_array()
    {

        a = new int[n];
        Node = new TextBox[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            //NODE
            a[i] = i;
            Node[i] = new TextBox();

            Node[i].Text = a[i].ToString();

            Node[i].Width = 80;
            Node[i].Height = 80;
            Node[i].Margin = new Thickness(2);
            Node[i].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            Node[i].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            BoxStack.Children.Add(Node[i]);
        }
    }

    private void btn_Random_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = r.Next(100);
            Node[i].Text = a[i].ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btn_Array_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        create_array();
    }
```

As you can see here I've subscribed a method to `TextBox.TextChanged` event, which will change my number `n` when user fills the box. Other things should be clear enough (I hope) for you. There is still some mess in your code (I haven't changed it on purpose - so that it will be easier for you to understand).

I've also removed Labels - hopefully you will be able to do it yourself. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I am trying to build a program can show step by step sorting algorithms ( bubble sort , quicksort , heap sort , etc ... ) for Nokia Lumia . I had successful built in Windows Form with TextBox and Label using System.Drawing but it's different in Windows Phone. My idea is: use TextBox for drawing BOXES, Label for showing NUMBER (random number). I tried your method but failed in TextBlock for replace Label

Comment: @user3465661 If you want to make a label beside the box, the consider (for example) using grid with rows/columns instead of stackpanel. Then in one row place your labels (textblocks) in second row textboxes. Grid will guarantee that your label will be above the textbox.